# Fetching records from Sql Server database is not working Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and sql-server database. Structure and data is proper and exist in database.

`:: {{ \App\Models\Setting::getSettings()->site_name }}`

Above code is not working and giving following error.

### Trying to get property of non-object (View: ..\resources\views\layouts\default.blade.php) (View: ..\resources\views\layouts\default.blade.php)

If anyone can help?

Comment: can you post your `getSetting` method's implementation

Comment: With all the information you've given us, we can tell you that `\App\Models\Setting::getSettings()` is not returning an object.